# Semantics of std::bind and/or std::forward

Tags: c++, c++11, parameter-passing, variadic-functions, stdbind

I find it very confusing that the following code fails to compile

```
#include <functional>

class Mountain {
public:
  Mountain() {}
  Mountain(const Mountain&) = delete;
  Mountain(Mountain&&) = delete;
  ~Mountain() {}
};

int main () {
  Mountain everest;
  // shouldn't the follwing rvalues be semantically equivalent?
  int i = ([](const Mountain& c) { return 1; })(everest);
  int j = (std::bind([](const Mountain& c) {return 1;},everest))();
  return 0;
}
```

The compilation error being:

```
$ g++ -std=c++20 test.cpp -o test
In file included from test.cpp:1:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/functional:486:26: error: no
      matching constructor for initialization of 'tuple<Mountain>'
        : _M_f(std::move(__f)), _M_bound_args(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)
                                ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/functional:788:14: note: in
      instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_Bind<(lambda at test.cpp:14:22)
      (Mountain)>::_Bind<Mountain &>' requested here
      return typename __helper_type::type(std::forward<_Func>(__f),
             ^
test.cpp:14:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::bind<(lambda at
      test.cpp:14:22), Mountain &>' requested here
  int j = (std::bind([](const Mountain& c) {return 1;}, everest))();
                ^
...
```

So `std::bind` sneakily tries to copy `everest` even though the lambda only wants a reference to it. Am I rubbing against a weird edge case that nobody cares about (eg. it is always possible to just lambda-capture a reference to `everest`) or is there a rationale? If the rationale is that bind is protecting me from calling the lambda after `everest` was destroyed, is there an unsafe version of bind that would not do that?

Comment: What is `nc`? Could you [edit] your question to include a definition of both `everest` and `nc`?

Comment: Declarations for `nc` and `everest` are missing in your example code. `std::bind` was made before lambdas existed. You should generally always use lambdas, never bind. If you want to use references with `std::bind` you need to use `std::ref` or `std::cref`.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Your example is missing symbols `everest` and `nc`! Use this as starting point: https://godbolt.org/z/zxh5sYafe !

Comment: `bind` is for *"capture"*, lambda equivalent would be `[nc]() { return 1; }` (which won't compile for similar reason).

Comment: Oops, copied an old version of the code. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, arguments to [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) would be copied (or moved).

> The arguments to bind are copied or moved, and are never passed by reference unless wrapped in [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) or [`std::cref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref).

You can use `std::cref` (or `std::ref`) instead. E.g.

```
int j = (std::bind([](const Mountain& c) {return 1;}, std::cref(everest)))();
//                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^       ^
```

[LIVE](https://godbolt.org/z/4xdvvY6Yd)