# std::bind behaves differently when passed a pointer vs reference

Tags: c++, vtable, stdbind, dynamic-dispatch

The goal is to get a functor to the `Base::Print`.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class Base {
 public:
  virtual void Print() {
      cout << "Base" << endl;
  }

  virtual function<void()> get_fx1() {
    return bind(&Base::Print, this);
  }

  virtual function<void()> get_fx2() {
    return bind(&Base::Print, *this);
  }
};

class Derived : public Base {
 public:
  virtual void Print() override {
    std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Derived d;
  Base *ptr = &d;
  ptr->Base::Print();           // prints Base (expecetd) #out1
  bind(&Base::Print, ptr)();    // prints Derived (expected Base) #out2
  ptr->get_fx1()();             // prints Derived (expected Base) #out3
  ptr->get_fx2()();             // prints Base (expected Derived because of out2 and out3) #out4

  cout << " -- " << endl;
  Derived d2;
  Base& ref = d2;
  ref.Base::Print();            // prints Base (expected) #out5
  bind(&Base::Print, ref)();    // prints Base (expected Derived because of out2 and out3. But this matches the behaviour with out4) #out6

  cout << " -- " << endl;
  (&ref)->Base::Print();        // prints Base (expected) #out7
  bind(&Base::Print, &ref)();   // prints Derived (I give up) #out8
  
  return 0;
}
```

I assumed that passing a pointer or a reference to `std::bind` is exactly the same. Clearly, I was wrong. It seems like when a reference is passed to `std::bind` you can prevent the vtable lookup. But when a pointer is passed to `std::bind` there is no way to prevent the vtable lookup. Empirically this is what it seems like.

So, the question is: does `std::bind` selectively skip the vtable lookup when a reference is passed?

I didn't find any reference only stating this.

Edit:
Link to [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCCSABykAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn5cFVXptfUEhWGR0bEJCnUNTdmtQ109xaUDAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMwcjeWADUJutuVF4MDuliB9gmGgCCG1s7mPuHTkPEmKyX13e3XqlGu2YbAUiSYK12Q3QByst22TAUCl2FnhTxMAHYYTddokvBFaHhkCBvrtdgA3PANLxiMmoPDoXbKYjBAgQWb7DHEklctBeAjPNwHNz7MyWFHmMz8wW7Vy0aGc9EAEW%2BnPJlOpx1O1UFpNp6FZl12wEwBAA%2BlRVFxWezMVzdu8CEsGLsIsE9eYAGzIpQgECM5mkXYEBB4BSzOW3EmK5URskUh3qk5nATa3X69bYQ3Gs2qMxW9E2rn2x3O10QD1e9i%2BpmCAMAKiDIbD6wLUduUeb0ZucIRuwV0TwpMw9JA2Nx%2BOQSJR1uJOLxBKJMdV8doNLpDOrLLZqEHxCZe3znJJkJ9PL5gql4r7TMHUJFksOEII6B9MvDWPZSrbaKVHbbt2ZuwsEwwT6l%2BBZXgOQ67FCv7vhWuy1okBDEM8CrCu6MEFkhxAALSXBWPp%2BoIaYWLaZEkgA9BR2Iboi8EQJgqiJJgKxPmyGyLAQXCci6DBumYnoooRG4BthswkbaVE0cyiIQTeuwMUxLEEFBFbsWY6ycWYnLYXh6ZGqa5qWuJTakeR5FSYktG9v28mKcxDiqSi6maby6w6chenYAZ2a5iZ0LmRZ1FWTJk5KApjEOSp9JyVBUSiH8TyoFQuxabshj0px6wuZxkidiSp73kK4q7DhOHChK54Pq%2BsEkrF9LoNptVhZgHp2pgKUHGhjVviS7xUAAdARVbMhJgVcpZ1n0ZFylDjlvIAKw8aW5ZCSNNbtVQ/nNpJwVTVO9mzTFtlxSxTCJalKVpRlqVuQNSK8oGwaIkBBDIAgmCIkGTxRAgTDkosKEAO6EAgt0EJI80EO6%2BW7IVVXFXeZUVUV0p8bKzVlgJ/WzF5w1EZuAXmZNoXTUpjnoFDaLLXxWOCd660EAGHo42Nuwk4IsknfSEAAJKGpBuxeIkUNxPKMZFsQToaG%2BrY3Bw8y0JwC28H4HBaKQqCcAKljWBCgPghsPCkAQmgK/MADWIALRo%2BicJIqtm5rnC8AoIC26b6sK6QcCwEgjEsbyJDkJQ9TAAoyiGJUQgIKgQNq8baAsIkdBMNUkchLQMdx2rGtJyn9AxHCRhcOsGjwkoDSkPndDRKErCrLwNeFwA8ry2fx07AfIDcxDhy7pDd7U%2BBq7w/CCCIYjsFIMiCIoKjqF7pC6K0BhGCg1jWPoeARG7kDzKgSHpG7HC8Nu0R7p98DzAoBvT7YT7BBn0ex533C8EDxBMIknA8IryuOyXlrDg2BVCByIChVQcR3Q4XdJIOGa9gC7FLgNDQqCFIV2iNUUMCkdZWEsAGXAhASDCnWFwWYvBPZaFmPMD6TAsAxFZKQK2Ns7YcAdqQXOZ8B5uw9mbGhbCzCAI1sAyh/D5g7lSM4SQQA%3D%3D)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67601773/4165552 - becuse std::bind has copy/move semantics. `bind(&Base::Print, std::ref(ref))();` this will print Derived. `[&ref](){ ref.Print(); }();` this as well.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind - also in the docs there is an example with `uniform_int_distribution` - generator is captured by copy.

Comment: A side note: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::bind()` cannot bind "normal" references. You are slicing your derived class to your base class, and then calling the virtual function on the sliced object. For which the virtual call correctly calls the base class function.

[`std::ref(...)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) can be used to bind functions that want references:

[How to bind function to an object by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187192/)

Comment: > you are slicing your derived class to your base class;
It's being assigned to a Base reference so the object isn't sliced. The proof is that when "Print" is called inside get_fx1 then Derived is printed.

Comment: @SamarthS in get_fx1 you are not slicing, because you provide a pointer, you're slicing when providing a reference to std::bind.

Comment: @Aedro my bad. Now I got what you said in the 1st comment. Thanks.
So is there no way to std::bind to a base class virtual method? Using lambdas fixes the problem. But I don't see a way with using just std::bind

Comment: @SamarthS I'm not sure what you want for which there is "no way". Providing "this" as a pointer does what you want? And i mentioned the `std::ref(...)` as general solution to binding references.

Comment: A pointer to virtual member function will always do the virtual lookup. You cannot inhibit virtual lookup as in `ref.Base::Print()`.

Comment: @Aedoro Your answer solves the confusion I had when I was posting this question.; I guess now what I'm trying to achieve is to make get_fx1 to return a functor created using std::bind that calls the Base::Print on an object of type Derived. Basically, void Base::fx_gg() { Base::Print(); bind(&Base::Print, this)();} --> They call different methods. But I want the second line to call the same method as the first one.